# How to install the openlayers config for eslint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, openlayers, eslint

https://github.com/openlayers/eslint-config-openlayers

Following the directions here, I did the following.

In the terminal I issued this command:

```
npm install eslint eslint-config-openlayers --save-dev
```

Then I editted the .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
"extends": [
    "openlayers",
    "airbnb-base"
],
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "jquery": true
}
}
```

Yet, I'm still getting errors from ESLint related to OpenLayers. For instance,

```
'ol' is not defined. (no-undef)
```

Comment: Where ? Can you show the file ?

Comment: And try importing openlayers AFTER airbnb-base, so openlayers settings will prevail.

Comment: Is it TypeScript? Or are you using webpack? If one of those, did you import/require 'ol'?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `.eslintrc.json`.

```
"globals": {
    "ol": false
}
```

This tells the linter that `ol` is defined elsewhere, in your case in a script sourced from html. [Details in the ESLint docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef#rule-details).